# How to install Linux on arm processors

Tags: linux, embedded, arm

I work on arm cortex-m3 microcontrollers for 3,5 months.I made several projects and programmed directly with st arm debugger for real time operations(motor drive, sensor and actuator applications....).But nowadays I am searching for running linux on arm processors and design embedded board for it.

According to my research, there are several embedded Linux kernel that can be used in arm processors and it is possible to install.But I couldn't find any instruction about installing these linux kernels on arm processor.Is there any complete tutorial to explain how to install any example Linux kernel to arm step by step.

What type of toolchains should i use ?

Should I use any programmer for installation and what type(JTAG/SWD/USART)?

Is there any restrictive situations?(I am not planning to use 8-bit simple processor.I am considering to use Arm v8 cortex A-53 )

Also I would like to inform you that I already used Raspberry pi,Intel Galileo..  Unix based embedded controller board for many applications.(I just would like to create new bride development board to obtain flexible hardware).

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you are considering ARM-based computers based on Cortex-A7 or A53, you may consider:

- Arch Linux: https://archlinuxarm.org/
- Debian: https://www.debian.org/ports/arm/
- Ubuntu: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/arm
- many other, you can look for in Google

Usually, they present a listing with supported platforms. For Arch Linux, you can check: https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms

About the installation, usually it requires the setup an SD card and booting from it. For Arch Linux, you can check: https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv6/raspberry-pi or http://elinux.org/ArchLinux_Install_Guide

On the other hand, note that the Cortex-M3 is more suited for microcontrollers, ASICs and SOCs. Usually, it is harder to install linux in these machines. You may check: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/19234/linux-on-arm-cortex-m3-series

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I am going to check them all

Answer (score 2):

Debian, Fedora and Arch, of the more popular distributions, all have ARM ports and a pretty comprehensive documentation on how to install. Please have a look at those and decide which one works best for you.

Comment: Could you please direct me to the specified link for them.I just need to know what i need in hardware and software part to install it.